# Querying a table with max() yealds strange results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with structure like

> id, href(string), active_users(integer), measured(datetime)

This table contains measurements for number of active users for a given site at the given time (hourly, i.e, there is historical data and you CAN have more than one row with identical href, but it will have a measured value).

I want to get the maximum number of active users for each href in a given interval along with when was this peak reached (i.e, in this month, tell me when did each href have it's peak active users and when).

The query I initially wrote looks like this:

```
SELECT href,
       max(active_users),
       measured AS peak_date
FROM users_peak
WHERE measured >= DATE('2016-09-07')            
      AND measured <= DATE('2016-10-07') 
GROUP BY href
```

The problem is that in the results, the date is not the date that this peak was reached. If I do a manual check (`SELECT * FROM users_peak WHERE href='one_of_the_hrefs_from_the_result' AND measured >= DATE('2016-09-07') AND measured <= DATE('2016-10-07')` and order it by the active_users value), the date in the records that corresponds to the peak is different. When I modify the query to look like this:

```
SELECT od.href,
       od.active_users,
       oddate.measured AS measured
     FROM users_peak AS oddate
     JOIN
         (SELECT href,
                 max(active_users) AS active_users
          FROM users_peak
          WHERE measured >= DATE('2016-09-07')
            AND measured <= DATE('2016-10-07')
          GROUP BY href) AS od ON od.href = oddate.href
     WHERE oddate.active_users = od.active_users
         AND measured >= DATE('2016-09-07')
         AND measured <= DATE('2016-10-07')
     GROUP BY od.href
```

It returns the right results. Why is the initial query returning non-corresponding dates?

Comment: You have made some bad assumptions about the way GROUP BY works. Most RDBMS's would reject your first query with an error since it includes fields in the SELECT portion of the statement that are not aggregated and don't appear in the GROUP BY portion of your statement. It's trying to aggregate your date but since you didn't tell it how to aggregate it's just randomly picking a date that corresponds to the `href`. Your second query is more correct for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is to get a row for each HREF with the peak

This can be done by keeping your query, but adding an `INNER JOIN` clause that will only give back the lines with the max value (and therefore elimintate/filter out the rows that are not representing the maximum)
.

```
SELECT href,
       active_users,
       measured AS peak_date
FROM users_peak a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT href, MAX(active_users) max
    FROM users_peak
    GROUP BY href
) b ON a.href = b.href AND a.max = b.max
WHERE 
    measured >= DATE('2016-09-07')            
    AND measured <= DATE('2016-10-07')
```